# E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks

Tags: ubuntu, apt

Answers on SO threads with same error message did not solve my case.

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Willing to install `v4l-utils` wit `apt` I get the following error message:

```
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 v4l-utils : Depends: libv4l-0 (= 1.14.2-1) but 1.18.0-2build1 is to be installed
             Depends: libv4l2rds0 (= 1.14.2-1) but 1.18.0-2build1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Following answer I found I tried to install `aptitude`, I then get the following error message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 aptitude : Depends: libapt-pkg5.0 (>= 1.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Finally when willing to install the dependency `libapt-pkg5.0`

```
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dictionaries-common : Depends: debconf (>= 1.5.5) but it is not going to be installed or
                                debconf-2.0
                       Depends: libtext-iconv-perl but it is not going to be installed
 gir1.2-gdm-1.0 : Depends: libgdm1 (>= 3.33.4) but it is not going to be installed
 glib-networking : Depends: gsettings-desktop-schemas but it is not going to be installed
 libfolks25 : Depends: folks-common (= 0.13.2-1) but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: libfolks-eds25 but it is not going to be installed
 libgoa-1.0-0b : Depends: libgoa-1.0-common (>= 3.36.1-0ubuntu1pop1~1625208841~20.04~63ed2dd) but it is not going to be installed
 libicu66 : Depends: tzdata (> 2019c-3ubuntu1~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

I have update & upgrade & autoremove and also try:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Same results.

Answer (score 0):

i get some error when i install `v4l-utils` wit `apt`

but i just remove`libv4l-0`and`libv4l2rds0`used

```bash
sudo apt remove libv4l-0
sudo apt remove libv4l2rds0
sudo apt autoclean && sudo apt autoremove
```

and then install again , it works